# Flutter IAP subscription

Tags: android, ios, flutter, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

I'm trying to setup a subscription IAP for my app. I have managed to purchase the sub via my app. The next stage is being able to edit the subscription and display details on the subscription via the app. I can't find much details on this here, or in the [in_app_purchase](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase) documentation.

Does anyone know how to do this, or what the best practices are?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Google play billing guide](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/subs#deep-link) gives a comprehensive guide on how to handle this.

Essentially, let the user edit their subscription via Google Play.

I did this simply using the [`url_launcher`](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) package as follows: 
`launch("https://play.google.com/store/account/subscriptions")`